# $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ the limit exists?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

I need know is this limit exist or doesn't exist.

**My work:**

Find the limit to large axis $X$

$C_1=((x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=0)$

Then

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-x^20+x0^2-0^3}{x^2+0^2}=x$

Find the limit to large axis $X$

$C_2=((x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=0)$

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{0^3-0^2y+0y^2-y^3}{0^2+y^2}=-y$

**My dude:** As the limit are different, then $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ doesn't exists. Can i conclude that with that reasoning?

Comment: In both cases $C_1$ and $C_2$ the limit is $0$ as in $C_1$, $x$ is also tending to $0$, similarly in $C_2$.

Answer (score 3):

note that $$x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3=x^2(x-y)+y^2(x-y)=(x-y)(x^2+y^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the substitution $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^3(\cos^3\theta-\cos^2\theta\sin \theta+\cos \theta \sin^2\theta-\sin^3\theta)}{r^2}.$$

Note, that the limit does tend to zero independently from the angle $\theta$ because the trigonometric functions are bounded.

You can also simplify

$$\cos^3\theta-\cos^2\theta\sin \theta+\cos \theta \sin^2\theta-\sin^3\theta$$
$$=\cos\theta(\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2\theta)-\sin \theta (\cos^2\theta +\sin ^2\theta)=\cos\theta-\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\left | \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} \right |= |x|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \le |x|.$$

Since $|x|\to 0,$ so does $\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}.$ You can do the same with the terms $x^2y,xy^2,y^3$ on top.